# Save coins when the server restarts?

Tags: minecraft

Moin I made my own script with coins. But when the server restarts the coins are set to 0 at each time someone has an idea how to set that that which can be saved. (Scripts not so long)

Here's the script:

```
command /coins:
    aliases: coin 
    trigger:
        send "&e&lEndless &7● &aDu hast &e%{coins::%player%}% &aCoins" to player
        
Command /pay [<player>] [<number>]:
    trigger:            
        if arg-1 is set:
            if arg-1 is not player:
                if arg-2 is smaller than {coins::%player%}:
                    remove arg-2 from {coins::%player%}
                    add arg-2 to {coins::%arg-1%}
                    send " &7Du hast &e%arg-2% Coins &7an &a%arg-1% &7gesendet!" to player
                    send " &7Du hast &e%arg-2% Coins &7von &a%player% &7erhalten!" to arg-1
                    stop
                        
                        
                else if arg-2 is bigger than {coins::%player%}:
                    send "&e&lEndless &7● &cDu hast nicht genügend &eCoins"
                    stop
                    
        
            else if arg-1 is player:
                send "&e&lEndless &7● &7Du kannst dir selber kein Geld geben!"
                stop
                
        
        else if arg-1 is not set:
            send "&e&lEndless &7● &7Nutze&8: &e/pay <Spieler> <Anzahl>"
            stop    

on first join:
    set {coins::%player%} to 2000
        
every 1 tick:
    loop all players:
        if {coins::%loop-player%} is below 0:
            set {coins::%loop-player%} to 0
        if {coins::%loop-player%} is not set:
            set {coins::%loop-player%} to 0     
            
command /removecoins [<player>] [<number>]:
    permission: coins.remcoins
    permission message: &e&lEndless &7● &c&lKeine Erlaubnis
    trigger:
        if arg-1 is set:
            if arg-2 is a number:
                remove arg-2 from {coins::%arg-1%}
                send "&e&lEndless &7● &7%arg-1% wurden &e%arg-2% Coins &7abgezogen!"
                stop
                
        if arg-1 is not set:
            send "&e&lEndless &7● &7Bitte gebe einen Spieler und Beitrag an!"
            stop                

command /admin [<player>] [<number>]:
    permission: coins.remcoins
    permission message: &e&lEndless &7● &c&lKeine Erlaubnis
    trigger:
        if arg-1 is set:
            if arg-2 is a number:
                remove arg-2 from {coins::%arg-1%}
                stop
                
        if arg-1 is not set:
            stop            

Command /addcoins [<player>] [<number>]:
    permission: coins.givecoins
    permission message: &e&lEndless &7● &c&lKeine Erlaubnis
    trigger:
        if arg-1 is set:
            if arg-2 is a number:
                add arg-2 to {coins::%arg-1%}
                send "&e&lEndless &7● &7%arg-1% hat &e%arg-2% Coins &7erhalten!"
                stop
                
            else if arg-2 is not a number:
                send "&e&lEndless &7● &7Das ist keine Anzahl!"
                
        if arg-1 is not set:
            send "&e&lEndless &7● &7Bitte gebe einen Spieler und Beitrag an!"
            stop
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use a mysql database and save coins in there.
then you can just create Statements and store them secure in a database, even if the servers are offline.
try this to connect:

```
    Connection conn = null;
try {
    // db parameters
    String url       = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqljdbc";
    String user      = "root";
    String password  = "secret";

    // create a connection to the database
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    // more processing here
    // ...  
} catch(SQLException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try{
           if(conn ! null)
             conn.close()
    }catch(SQLException ex){
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
on server stop:
        save-all
        set {coins ::%players%} to "%{coins ::%players%}%"
```

You need to make it make sure it saves it and the game it will set all online players coins to what they have to try and save it also saves the game to save skript and the coins on the server stop.